# Can you use .filter and .get in the same query for Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a database where data is organized by a number that is unique, and a name that isn't unique. for example:

```
NumCOL:  NameCOL:
1        Jay
2        Joel
3        Joey
4        Joel
```

Could I use a filter and get statement to grab names where the number is equal to a certain number? Let's say I have a form that lets a user pick a number from the database and the user picks the number 2.

```
num = request.POST.get('FormNumber') #num = 2
name = Database.objects.filter(NumCOL=num).get('NameCOL')
return HttpResponse(name)
```

Can something like this be done? I want to grab the name wherever the user selects based on their number. Based on the code I should get a response `Joel`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Er, that's not what `get` does. It's for getting a single item that matches a query, not for getting a single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by daniel in the comments and by metmirr in his answer, you don't need to do it like this. The following works just fine.

```
name = Database.objects.get(NumCOL=num)
return HttpResponse(name.NameCOL)
```

Retrieving all the fields of a single model does not add any overhead whatsoever to the query. Get is used to retrieve a single row and not a single column.

To retrieve a single column, you can do:

```
name = Database.objects.filter(NumCOL=num).values('NameCol')
```

To retrieve a single cell you can do

```
name = Database.objects.filter(NumCOL=num).values_list('NameCol', flat=True)
```

As a side note, by convention we name the model with the first letter in upper case and fields are all lower case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This information will be very helpful!

Comment: all the best with your project

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably be hearing from you again

Answer (score 2):

```
name = Database.objects.get(NumCOL=num)
#name = Database.objects.filter(NumCOL=num)
return HttpResponse(name.NameCOL)
```